# Rails server won't start up

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to do a **Rails server** won't start, I'm using linux to run the code.

Console result:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/oblivio/Applications/Ruby/blog/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Someone will want more information about the environment, like where you are loading the `bundler/setup` file from or if it's available.

Comment: do you use rvm or rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

try to type 'spring stop' in your rails app. And retry 'rails s'